# DNN theme not loaded after migration

Tags: sql-server, windows, iis, themes, dotnetnuke

I'm absolutely new to DNN world, and I have to migrate a bunch of websites from a web server to another.

Following my expectations and some "guide" on the web, i did:

- Exported SqlServer databases from old server
- Imported all databases in new server
- Copied the whole c:\inetput\vhosts directory from old server to the new one
- Created manually the vhosts entries in IIS to host the websites (setting the vhost on the httpdocs dir and converting to application the subfolder "portal"

After some problem with app pool, user permissions, database user configurations etc. i reached to get websites running.

But what it happens is that the websites seems to load the default "theme" instead of the one that was using in production server. What did I forgot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is likely an Error that is being thrown with the current "skin" so you'll need to get into the Event Viewer (under the admin page) if you can get logged in, or into the EventLog table in the database to see what errors are being thrown.

```
select top 50 * From eventlog order by logcreatedate desc
```

Comment: Ok, it absolutely helped me in understand the problem. There were some  file permissions problems,  some unicode characters in sources seen as invalid character, some 32bit assembly that were disabled in app pool.. and so on. But without this hint i wouldn't figure out where to look. Thank you very much!